# !D/EGL_emulation

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, emulation, console.log

After using the !D/EGL_emulation filter to hide the app time stats in flutter I get this annoying label next to the filter text field that tells me how many lines have been hidden in the console log |Showing 122/444| , is there any way to remove this ?!

It's ticking every second and I want to remove it.